# Online Excel Sheet that get updated by 10 ppl

Tags: excel, live

I have an Excel sheet that 10 ppl share and update periodically. we are having it on a network share. i wonder if there is a web based interface that i can use to represent this sheet and let the ppl update it online. of course it does not need to be an excel sheet online. i couldnt find the right words to search for it actually. i would like to host it on my web server. it says it is closed but i was waiting for some php web based application that i can put on one of my hosts. anyway thanx for all
Regards to all

Comment: Try Google Docs or SkyDrive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose one of the many [online spreadsheet applications](http://mashable.com/2008/02/05/forget-excel-14-online-spreadsheet-applications/)
otherwise you will allways have locking issues.

Comment: good applications i went through them. didnt test all of them yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Google Docs`](http://docs.google.com) or [`Excel Web App`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/introduction-to-excel-web-app-HA010378338.aspx)

Comment: thanx it can be a good solution. i tested google docs but not yet excel web app

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Online excels available like Google Docs,[Zoho Sheet](https://sheet.zoho.com/excelviewer), [Edit Grid](http://www.editgrid.com)